# What R test to use?

Tags: r, self-study

I'm having trouble figuring out what test to run for the following problem. I'm not sure if I need to make up x values, or if there is a test to run using x (mean of Farm B) and x-6 (mean of Farm A).

You are an apple wholesale buyer. Larger “Fireside” apples (larger by weight per apple) command higher retail prices per kg. You got offers of the same price per kg for Fireside apples from Farms A and B. It is known that the weights of apples from each Farm have a normal distribution with the standard deviation of 15 grams. You weighed each of 10 randomly chosen apples from each farm and ran a t-test with a 99% confidence level to compare the mean apple weights from the two farms. Unknown to you, the average weight of apples from Farm A is 6 grams lower than that from Farm B.

(1)   What is the chance that you can make the right call that the mean weight of apples from Farm B is higher than that from Farm A?

(2)   If you want to have the chance to make the right call higher than 70%, how many apples from each farm at minimum do you need to weigh?

Comment: Even more than Stack Overflow, the stats.stackexchange community appreciates it when people tag homework questions as such and describe what they have tried. It would help if you mentioned what tests and methods you've learned about recently, and if you have any guesses as to which might be appropriate. It makes it feel less like we're doing homework for you that way.

Comment: If it is a homework question, it is phrased badly. 99% is not a "confidence level", it is 1 - significance level. You cannot make the call  "that the mean weight of apples from Farm B is higher than that from Farm A" because the initial hypothesis is two-sided.